# NLTK plot dependency graph

Tags: nltk, dependency-graph

I'd like to plot graphs like this with NLTK. But I am not sure where is such an example in NLTK. Could anybody show some example NLTK code to plot such kind of figures? Thanks.

http://universaldependencies.org/introduction.html

Comment: Did you mean the Dependency Parsing graph?